# Scaling only HiDPI display with xrandr in dual monitor set-up

Tags: linux-mint, xrandr, displayport

I recently installed Linux Mint 18 on my ThinkPad T460p. Having a dual monitor set-up with a internal HiDPI display and a full HD external display connected via Display Port, I tried to adjust the scaling factor of the internal one while leaving the external one untouched.

For that matter, I first ran `xrandr -q` to check the respective ports, and, subsequently,

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --auto --output DP-1-2-8 --auto --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP-1-1
```

As a result, the following error messages were printed:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  26 (RRSetCrtcTransform)
Value in failed request:  0x40
Serial number of failed request:  47
Current serial number in output stream:  48
```

The same was printed when running

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --auto --output DP-1-2-8 --auto --panning 3840x2400+2560+0 --scale 2.0x2.0 --right-of eDP-1-1
```

To me, these error messages are entirely cryptic. The lack of information on the opcodes makes this a difficult, almost undebugable problem for me. For the commands, I followed the instructions given on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Multiple_displays).

What intuitively might be of interest to that problem is that instead of running nouveau, I run the proprietary nvidia (nvidia-367, to be precise) drivers to power my GeForce 940MX.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: If for a moment forget the HiDPI scaling, have you succeed to have both monitors operating, either as mirror or desktop extension....?

Comment: Yes, besides the scaling factor everything works fine. I have the external monitor set up as a desktop extension.

Comment: I never found the method to set different scaling factors for different displays TBH. The graphic driver support is not nearly as good as on Windows, especially for newer NVidia cards. I currently just go along with 1920x1080 on a 15'' screen. The characters are a bit smaller but not that unbearable. Maybe you can consider using some software scaling on your laptop screen instead of through display setting?

Comment: Well, according to the ArchWiki article I linked, setting different scaling factors for different displays should work. However, it is likely that this tutorial was written with noveau (or bumblebee) in mind, an open source alternative to the drivers from nvidia. I am going with your suggestion for now, but hope this problem will be resolved at one point.

Comment: @foobar Could you try my answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/867431/26246 (method2 using `nvidia-settings`) , I think `xrandr` will work with any scaling function (based on `--transform` that's includes `--scale` & `--scale-from`) . all I can say some nvidia adapters with nvidia proprietary driver version combination don't work even with `--scale 1x1` which is the default anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, when opening the display settings tab of the nvidia settings panel, I only see one display (that is, the two physical monitors are displayed as only one). Do you by chance know the reason for this?